# java.net.PortUnreachableException: ICMP Port Unreachable - Kerberos error

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, kerberos-delegation, mit-kerberos

I am trying to run a kafka cluster with Kerberos auth enabled.
kafka broker, zookeeper & kdc (kerberos) servers are started as containers inside a docker network.

Kafka broker port 9092 has been mapped to host machine so able to call broker from host machine network.

As client has to first interact with Kdc for kerberos auth, port 88 of KDC container also has been exposed and open from host machine.

docker ps (for kdc container):
a856bfe3f330   plaintext_kdc                                     "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   11 hours ago   Up 11 hours     0.0.0.0:88->88/tcp, :::88->88/tcp                                                                                                                             kdc

/etc/krb5.conf :

```
[realms]
    TEST.CONFLUENT.IO = {
            kdc = 10.0.1.207      --(tried localhost also here)
    }
```

Able to telnet localhost 88 from host machine.
But getting below error when I try to run a producer from host machine :
(Note : able to produce and consume message within docker network, producing from a client docker container inside the same docker network)

/home/ubuntu/kafka-docker-for-nifi-integration/kafka_install/kafka_2.11-2.4.0/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:29092 --topic kafka-nifi-sasl_gssapi_plaintext --producer.config producer_kt.properties
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:432)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:298)
at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:45)
at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: ICMP Port Unreachable
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:158)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:146)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:67)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:99)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:450)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:421)
... 3 more
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: ICMP Port Unreachable
at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:786)
at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:592)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:726)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:665)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:663)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:663)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:574)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin.login(AbstractLogin.java:60)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin.login(KerberosLogin.java:103)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.(LoginManager.java:62)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:112)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:147)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.PortUnreachableException: ICMP Port Unreachable
at java.base/java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:181)
at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:814)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.UDPClient.receive(NetClient.java:205)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(KdcComm.java:404)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(KdcComm.java:364)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:348)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.sendIfPossible(KdcComm.java:253)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:229)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:200)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:345)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:498)
at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:754)

Thanks
Mahendra

Comment: Did you solve this?